# How to change subscription from PlanA to PlanB using Stripe with Python/Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I can create a Stripe subscription for a customer using the following code :

```
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=stripe_customer_id,
                items=[
                    { "plan": stripe_plan_A },
                ]
            )
```

Here is what I see on Stripe Dashboard.

[image]

I want to change the upgrade the subscription to stripe_plan_B but while keeping rest of the configuration same.

I have experimented with the following code to change the plan from stripe_plan_A to stripe_plan_B; however this following command results in having two subscriptions at the same time, rather than a single subscription.

```
                stripe.Subscription.modify(
                    subscription.id,
                    items=[
                        { "plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_B },
                    ]
                )
```

As you can see below, we can have two subscriptions at the same time for the same user. (Stripe docs say you can have n number of subscriptions)

[image]

Is there any suggestion for this, so I can fluently change between the plans ?

Comment: user can have multiple subcription ? can you share code ?

Comment: Yes, you can have n number of subscriptions with the same user.

Comment: Then you can delete the plan A first then add plan B. I think this is the API documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/delete?lang=python

Comment: if you can store subscription then you can add option in them in db that they are active or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price replaces Plan and Price is the recommended for creating a subscription. I'd recommend refering to the migration Price to Plan migration here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/migrating-prices

You can update the subscription directly with subscription item ID. By setting [items[0][id]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items-id) you are indicating that you want to update an existing SubscriptionItem, and can update it to use a different price. For example,

```
sub = stripe.Subscription.modify(
  sub.id, 
  items=[
    {"id": {{SUB_ITEM_ID}}, "price": {{PRICE_B_ID}} },
  ],
)
```

Alternatively, you can also delete the existing SubscriptionItem with [`deleted`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items-deleted) parameter to `true` and add the new SubscriptionItem. For example,

```
sub = stripe.Subscription.modify(
  sub.id, 
  items=[
    {"id": {{SUB_ITEM_ID}}, "deleted": "true" },
    {"price": {{PRICE_B_ID}} },
  ],
)
```

Comment: How can I switch from Plan A to Plan B, without giving an explicit price to modify function. The price of Plan B is well known. Is there any option to switch directly from planA to planB with proration ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following answer in Stripe's page [enter link description here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade):

```
subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve('sub...')

stripe.Subscription.modify(
  subscription.id,
  cancel_at_period_end=False,
  proration_behavior='create_prorations',
  items=[{
    'id': subscription['items']['data'][0].id,
    'price': 'price_...',
  }]
)
```